Redis vector search with filters failing on Python
I’m trrying to do a vector search on memory db with filters. Using the redis client on Python. I have been getting an error when trying to apply filters. I think the syntax is probably not right and appreciate any information.
Error:
> Parse error at 0 Unexpected `(` Expected whitespaces

Actual command sent to memory db :
(
    'FT.SEARCH',
    'sbm_ads',
    '(@ad_group_id:300019538580004 @campaign_id:300006849635006) => [KNN 50 @embedding $vec_param AS vector_score]',
    'RETURN',
    6,
    'asin',
    'expression',
    'bid',
    'ad_group_id',
    'campaign_id',
    'vector_score',
    'SORTBY',
    'vector_score',
    'ASC',
    'DIALECT',
    4,
    'LIMIT',
    0,
    10,
    'params',
    2,
    'vec_param',
    b'\x88\xb9??\x04U)>\xca\xc4T> \x97\xb0\xbe\xdfe[\xbeB;\n\xbf\xda;\x16?\xec\xe5z\xbf8\x85\x12\xbdY\xafw?\x84\xf9a\xbf?P2?\x8c\x9f\xeb\xbd\xa8\xd4D?\xb2\xba_\xbf\xd4o\x9c\xbekja>)\xae\xe3\xbeF!=?T\x9ez\xbf G\x8a\xbe^\xd03\xbf\x0b\xd05?\xces\x81>$=\x85=v\xb2~?wke\xbf\x19\xc5\x06\xbe\xdf?Q\xbe\x10\x14:?\x90\xf9\x0f?m\x0f\x1f\xbe \x9e1>\xfd\x16\x06\xbf\x13h?>\x83\x16\x94>\x1bg\t\xbf\xdd\\/>z\xf2\x92>\x84k\xee>\xaev\xbb\xbe\x90\xa48\xbf\x96G_?@\x18\x04\xbfq\xe0\xe9\xbe\xc7\xe9\xfc\xbe\xad\x8bV?xUO>\x16\x99B?\x8d\xfc\xb5\xbe\n\xb7\xe1>a\xefT?\xfd\xb9e>#f\xe6<N\x1e@?\xeeL\xde>d\xb4I?\x986\x1b\xbf\x8c\x90\x0b?F\xfb\xb7=\xff\x981?\xcb[V=\xe3\x8bj\xbf6\xdd\xd8='
)

(Removing parentheses doesn’t help)
python code

    def search_vectors(index_name, vector_field_name, input_vector, k=10, fields=[], filters=None):
         """Performs a vector similarity search and returns the top K results."""
         fields.append("vector_score")
         if filters:
             filter_query_str = " ".join([f"@{field}:{value}" for field, value in filters.items()])
         else:
             filter_query_str = "*"
         query_str = f"({filter_query_str}) => [KNN {k} @{vector_field_name} $vec_param AS vector_score]"
     #     print(query_str)
         query = Query(query_str).return_fields(*fields).sort_by("vector_score").dialect(4)
         params = {"vec_param": input_vector}
         result = asin_memdb_client.ft(index_name).search(query, params)
         return result

Full Error:

--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ResponseError                             Traceback (most recent call
last) Cell In[42], line 13
11     _fields = ["asin","expression","bid","ad_group_id","campaign_id"]
12     start = time.time()
---> 13     results = search_vectors(asin_memdb_client, "sbm_ads", "embedding", random_vector, 50, _fields, filters)
14     print("Elapsed Time:", time.time() - start)
15 #     print(results)
Cell In[41], line 14, in search_vectors(client, index_name,
vector_field_name, input_vector, k, fields, filters)
12 query = Query(query_str).return_fields(*fields).sort_by("vector_score").dialect(2)
13 params = {"vec_param": input_vector}
---> 14 result = client.ft(index_name).search(query, params)
15 return result
File
~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/commands/search/commands.py:508,
in SearchCommands.search(self, query, query_params)
505 if get_protocol_version(self.client) not in ["3", 3]:
506     options[NEVER_DECODE] = True
--> 508 res = self.execute_command(SEARCH_CMD, *args, **options)
510 if isinstance(res, Pipeline):
511     return res
Cell In[17], line 7, in LoggingRedis.execute_command(self, *args,
**kwargs)
5 def execute_command(self, *args, **kwargs):
6     print(f"Executing: {args}")
----> 7     return super().execute_command(*args, **kwargs)
File
~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/client.py:559,
in Redis.execute_command(self, *args, **options)
558 def execute_command(self, *args, **options):
--> 559     return self._execute_command(*args, **options)
File
~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/client.py:567,
in Redis._execute_command(self, *args, **options)
565 conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
566 try:
--> 567     return conn.retry.call_with_retry(
568         lambda: self._send_command_parse_response(
569             conn, command_name, *args, **options
570         ),
571         lambda error: self._disconnect_raise(conn, error),
572     )
573 finally:
574     if not self.connection:
File
~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/retry.py:62,
in Retry.call_with_retry(self, do, fail)
60 while True:
61     try:
---> 62         return do()
63     except self._supported_errors as error:
64         failures += 1
File
~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/client.py:568,
in Redis._execute_command..()
565 conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
566 try:
567     return conn.retry.call_with_retry(
--> 568         lambda: self._send_command_parse_response(
569             conn, command_name, *args, **options
570         ),
571         lambda error: self._disconnect_raise(conn, error),
572     )
573 finally:
574     if not self.connection:
File
~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/client.py:542,
in Redis._send_command_parse_response(self, conn, command_name, *args,
**options)
538 """
539 Send a command and parse the response
540 """
541 conn.send_command(*args, **options)
--> 542 return self.parse_response(conn, command_name, **options)
File
~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/client.py:581,
in Redis.parse_response(self, connection, command_name, **options)
579 try:
580     if NEVER_DECODE in options:
--> 581         response = connection.read_response(disable_decoding=True)
582         options.pop(NEVER_DECODE)
583     else:
File
~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/connection.py:616,
in AbstractConnection.read_response(self, disable_decoding,
disconnect_on_error, push_request)
614 if isinstance(response, ResponseError):
615     try:
--> 616         raise response
617     finally:
618         del response  # avoid creating ref cycles
ResponseError: Parse error at 0 Unexpected ( Expected whitespaces


Please include the full traceback error.
